# How to go to particular activity after the screen is turned on using WakefulBroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to  go to particular activity after the screen is turned on using WakefulBroadcastReceiver. the screen is properly turning on but it is not performing action after that, and not even showing any kind of exception.

Following is my code.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<receiver android:name=".Alarm" />
```

**Java File**

```
public class Alarm extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            isScreenOn = powerManager.isInteractive();
        }
        else
        {
            isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
        }
        if(!isScreenOn)
        {
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"Remind Me");
            wakeLock.acquire();
            Intent gotoIntent;
            gotoIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            gotoIntent.putExtra(ReminderActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(mReceivedID));
            context.startActivity(gotoIntent);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is your broadcastreceiver registered in your manifest file ?

Comment: @GrIsHu yes, it is registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a perfect answer for my own question:
I just have to use **gotoIntent.addFlags(Intent.[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))** while creating intent

```
    Intent gotoIntent;
    gotoIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    gotoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    gotoIntent.putExtra(ReminderActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(mReceivedID));
    context.startActivity(gotoIntent);
```